# Templated Matrix in RCPP

Tags: c++, r, matrix, vector, rcpp

I'm using Rcpp to make a function that takes a matrix and a vector and I'd like both of them to be the same templated type. Is there anyway to do this? It seems that you have to declare a matrix as numeric or something before using it.

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void MyFunc(Matrix<T> templated_matrix, std::vector<T> set_row)
{
    templated_matrix(0, _) = row;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity of the question. This is probably so simple that it's tossing people for a loop and I'm mostly curious about how to get a templated matrix. Some code has been added.

Comment: Given the update, I think the question can now be properly answered.

Comment: Agreed, @KevinUshey.  Seems like the usual template-on-the-outside, but dynamic-dispatch-on-the-inside due to C being C, and R being done in R.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of issues intermingling here. In particular, Rcpp attributes does not handle exporting of template functions, so you cannot write:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
template <typename T>
void MyFunc(T object) { ... }
```

This is because typing in R is dynamic (done and stored at runtime), which C++ typing is static (everything must be known at compile time). You need to manually generate a bridge between the dynamic and static worlds.

A common approach is to make a template function and a 'dispatch' function, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void MyFuncImpl(T object) { .... }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void MyFunc(SEXP object)
{
    switch (TYPEOF(object))
    {
    case INTSXP: return MyFuncImpl<IntegerVector>(object);
    case REALSXP: return MyFuncImpl<NumericVector>(object);
    ...
    }
}
```

In your case, you might need to separate dispatch based on whether the object passed in is a matrix, e.g. `if (Rf_isMatrix(object)) { ... } else { .... }`.

You might find these articles on the [Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/) helpful:

- http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/
- http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dynamic-dispatch-for-sparse-matrices/

As an aside -- if you want to template directly on the underlying type of R object, you could also write:

```
template <int RTYPE>
void MyFuncImpl(Vector<RTYPE> object) { .... }
```

which may or may not be more useful, depending on your needs.